# How to set tabindex in dynamic generated textbox inside listView in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, textbox, tabindex

We built our user interface from XML definitions (not XAML) but underneath we use a WPF to present the UI. That is at runtime, we create the WPF UI based on our XML definition.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="400px" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ListView" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
              SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False">

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="grid">
                        <GridViewColumn  Width="100px"> 
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModuleName}"  Width="100px" Foreground="Black" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn  Width="200px">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ModuleUserCount, TargetNullValue=''}" MaxLength="6" Name="txtModuleUserCount" KeyDown="txtModuleUserCount_KeyDown" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="200" BorderBrush="Gray"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>       
                 </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

I generate 4 module through XML SO UI have four `TextBox` in these dynamic `TextBox` tabIndex is not working. I tried `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"` but it's not working. How to make tab navigation work for this layout?

Answer (score 0):

I know its too too late, but I would like to answer. I had the same problem. I tried following way and it resolved my problem: Set:

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="10"
```

or whatever value you require in `ListView` itself.